# How can I send report on stop locust (as lib mode)

Tags: testing, locust

I want to send out report: example how many percent failures to group telegram on stop locust

It is for total request, it is not in method on_stop for each user instance

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Use the `test_stop` event as documented here: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html

Specifically, if you wanted to print your fail ratio you would do:

```
@events.test_stop.add_listener
def on_test_stop(environment, **kwargs):
    print(environment.runner.stats.total.fail_ratio)
```

Another example is here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/test_data_management.py